# Can Linux programs run malicous code after installation? even if they're never opened?

Tags: permissions, login, security, users

I have two accounts on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, `user1` and `admin`.

The accounts breakdown as follows:

- `user1` I run untrusted, basically **any** programs, `/home/user1` permissions are `-rwxr-x---`
- `admin` I only run trusted programs, `/home/admin` permissions are `-rwxr-----` to allow `user1` to see my home directory, read the files, but not *mess* with them.

The installation of programs from the Software Center is system wide. Even if I only run the *un-trusted* programs on the `user1` account they still exist on the `admin` account. So is my setup still *safe*? I know you don't necessarily need to run a program for it to execute things.

In short, can the *Trojan_Horse_Bad_Guy* program that I only run on the `user1` account still mess with the home drive of my `admin account`? Do I have to actually open and use it on the admin account for it to cause harm? Or can it run silently, unknown in the background, while I'm logged in as admin, since it was installed system wide when I did `sudo apt-get install bad_guy_program` from my `user1` account?

I'm trying to protect my /home/admin directory from some program deleting it, messing with it, uploading it, or whatever else could go wrong.

Comment: If something can read it, then it can upload the data to somewhere else. If you want to prevent that, the only way would be to limit read permission to only that user. But I'm not quite sure what your'e asking here. When you install a deb, you're already granting root to that package, so it can do anything it wants from that point on (assuming it's malicious), as root.

Comment: I didn't know that. That ruins my plan. Ideally I'd like to sandbox any *suspect* apps (anything not trusted) to my `user1` account. To prevent those apps from messing with my *protected* `/home/admin` directory. I know Snap/Flatpak can do this but the niche scientific programs I run don't have Flatpaks. And I have no way of knowing if I can trust these niche programs from messing with my home directory files. Shucks.

Comment: I think what you want is _apparmor_ then. You would probably need to write apparmor rules for those apps and put them in enforcing mode. You can check out the latest _firejail_ perhaps and see if it has rules for your apps.